How to serve static html file on root of Azure App Service?
I created a {my_custom_name}.html file in the wwwroot folder of my App Service. The file contains a string of plain text. I want to make this file accessible from a web browser from the root of the web like this: https://{name}.azurewebsites.net/{my_custom_name}.html
I am always ending on error 404 Not Found. I am sure the file exists in the wwwroot folder. I checked it with Kudu. I also checked if the name of the file is correct in wwwroot folder and also in the web address. Everything seems to be okay, however I am not able to get the context of the file.
My Azure Web App is using .NET 7 (STS).

Yes,it is possible..What is the framework of your app?

I use .NET 7 (STS) on Windows backend infrastructure. Can you please tell me how it is possible?

Is your file on any folder or in the root of the application in local?

The file is in the wwwroot folder.

Please share the screencap of the local and deployed app file.

Where is the file in local and where it is deployed in KUDU App service ?

Sorry but why you need printscreen of that? I have my file physically here: 'site\wwwroot{my_custom_name}.html'

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The issue is with your .NET 7 Core version.
I don't see any .NET Core 7 option while creating the App Service.


I have tried with the Core 8.
You can see the .NET 7 is deprecated.



I am able to access the static file from the root directory without changing any configurations.




Azure App Service allows you to access any static file which is added in the root directory by default.

If you want to access the static file deployed from the local (deployed to Azure App Service from Visual Studio),


Refer this SOThread which I have answered.
